# When did David Hamelech write Tehillim?

Tags: history, tehilim-psalms, writing-printing, king-david

When did David Hamelech write Tehillim? Or to be more technical, when did David write his first Tehillim and when did he write his last?
Also was there a certain period of time within which he wrote a lot of the Tehillim?

Answer (score 5):

David HaMelech wasn't the sole author of psalms — the earliest mention of someone reciting psalms is found in [bava batra 14b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.14b.12) (on the bottom); which says that king David compiled psalms from a number of people from as early back as Adam harishon.

Answer (score 4):

To answer one part of your question:

King David wrote his last psalm (Psalm 72) close to his death, when he appointed King Shlomo as his successor. See [Metzudot David and Rashi on 72:20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50393&pgnum=405).